# Defining a filterF function that can be used with any Foldable type

Tags: haskell, filter

Source: Hutton, Graham. "*Programming in Haskell*" (p. 267)

> 5. Using foldMap, define a generic version of the higher-order function filter on lists that can be used with any foldable type:

> `filterF :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> [a]`

I am doing this exercise and have some questions:

- Isn't the correct type `filterF :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> t a` ? Isn't filter supposed to preserve the structure of the container ?

This is my attempt; is it correct ? Should I place a `Monoid` restriction on `t` ?

```
filterF :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> t a
filterF p = foldMap (\x -> if p x then pure x else mempty)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foldable is not powerful enough to implement a filter operation that preserves the shape of the container. I often think of Foldable as "anything you could make into a list". Notably this does not mean you could make a list back into a specific Foldable type. Thus, this filterF can only return `[a]`.

Your implementation is fine, but doesn't match your type signature. Ask GHCI for the type, and you will find:

```
> :t filterF
filterF
  :: (Foldable t, Monoid (f a), Applicative f) =>
     (a -> Bool) -> t a -> f a
```

This can be specialized to the type that the book asks for  (`Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> [a]`), but not to the type you think this operation should have (`Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> t a`). In particular, you claim that `t ~ f`, but you can't actually promise that: you use a *different* type, which must be Monoid and Applicative but need not be Foldable, to build up the return value.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Could you clarify ? When you said that I used a different type...which is the one you are talking about ?

Comment: @F.Zer Your implementation returns a type `f` which is Applicative and Monoid. It does not return the same `t` that the input was. *If* `t` is both Applicative and Monoid, that can be the same as `f` (e.g., when applied to a list you can return a list). But you can't do it for *all* Foldables, which is what's promised by the signature you tried to apply.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification !